# What's the difference between the questions I'm shown on the main page of SO.com versus when I click on the "Questions" link?

Tags: discussion, questions, user-interface, content

I notice when I visit the main page of `stackoverflow.com` I see a distinctly different list of questions than when I click on the "Questions" link that takes me to `stackoverflow.com/questions`.  What's the difference between these two sets of questions?

I notice that the list I see on `stackoverflow.com` when I first visit the site seems to be biased toward my interesting tags, but not all of the questions that show up contain a tag I've marked as interesting.  How are these selected?  Is there an algorithm trying to determine other questions outside my interests that I might want to look at?  Are the questions chosen by recency, least answers, longest time without an accept, etc.?  And is the `stackoverflow.com/questions` more just the overall list of the most recent questions?

Just curious.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

the Questions page is a simple flat list of unfiltered questions, with whatever sort tab you have selected.

Comment: Thanks! That's really interesting.  Teach me to not keep up with the blog...